# If I change the folder, why is the "ModuleNotFouldError" happened?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda

My environment is Windows10, and I installed python3.6, tensorflow, and anaconda.
There is no error in the installation.

If I run the "command prompt" (not use anaconda), I can success to run tensorflow.
However, if I use anaconda, a problem is coming.

1st: If I run anaconda prompt and import tensorflow by python, no problem.
2nd: If I change the folder and import tensorflow, the error message "ModuleNotFouldError" is coming.

Why I change the path, I cannot import a module?

History is below.

---

```
(c:\Users\**Username**\Anaconda3) c:\Users\**Username**\>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information
>>>import tensorflow
>>>exit()

(c:\Users\**Username**\Anaconda3) c:\Users\**Username**\>cd workspace
(c:\Users\**Username**\Anaconda3) c:\Users\**Username**\workspace>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC 1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information
>>>import tensorflow
Trackback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: do you have downloaded tensorflow or have a directory named tensorflow inside ```c:\Users\**Username**\``` ?

Comment: I installed tensorflow by using pip3. python3 is installed in C:\python35. Tensorflow is in that folder.